# How can I improve my OpenCV Sudoku solver's digit recognition?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pytorch

I've been trying for a while to successfully extract and classify the digits from a picture of a sudoku grid, and I've been struggling to get any form of accuracy. I've tried tweaking various things, including inverting the image and cropping the edges of each square, but nothing seems to improve.

This is my code for the image processing:

```
# load model.pt
model = LargerModel(10)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model.pth'))
model.eval()

img_path = 'sudoku_test.jpg'

def process_image(img_path, img_width=450, img_height=450):
    # Read the image
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img_resize = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height))

    #Preprocess the image
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_resize, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 1)
    img_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img_blur, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)

    return img_thresh

def contours(img):   
    # Find the contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # img_contours = img.copy()
    # cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    return contours

def biggest_contour(contours): 
    # Find the biggest contour
    biggest_contour = np.array([])
    max_area = 0
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > 50:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.02 * peri, True)
            if area > max_area and len(approx) == 4:
                biggest_contour = approx
                max_area = area
    return biggest_contour

# Reorder the points in the contour to go clockwise
def reorder(points):
    points = points.reshape((4, 2))
    points_new = np.zeros((4, 1, 2), dtype=np.int32)
    add = points.sum(1)
    points_new[0] = points[np.argmin(add)]
    points_new[3] = points[np.argmax(add)]
    diff = np.diff(points, axis=1)
    points_new[1] = points[np.argmin(diff)]
    points_new[2] = points[np.argmax(diff)]
    return points_new

# Warp the image
def warp(img, biggest_contour, img_width=450, img_height=450):
    pts1 = np.float32(biggest_contour)
    pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0], [img_width, 0], [0, img_height], [img_width, img_height]])
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
    img_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (img_width, img_height))
    return img_warped
# Create a Sudoku grid
def split_grid(img):
    rows = np.vsplit(img, 9)
    squares = []
    for r in rows:
        cols = np.hsplit(r, 9)
        for box in cols:
            squares.append(box)
    return squares

# Predict the digits
def predict_digits(squares, img_width=450, img_height=450):
    result = []
    for image in squares:
        img = image[4:img_width-4, 4:img_height-4]
        img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28))
        img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
        img = img / 255.0
        img = torch.Tensor(img).view(-1, 1, 28, 28)
        outputs = model(img)
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
        probability = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)[0].item()
        if probability > 0.7:
            result.append(predicted.item())
        else:
            result.append(0)
    return result

img_path = 'sudoku_test.jpg'

img_processed = image_processing.process_image(img_path)
contours = image_processing.contours(img_processed)
biggest_contour = image_processing.biggest_contour(contours)
biggest_contour = image_processing.reorder(biggest_contour)

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
img_resize = cv2.resize(img, (450, 450))

#Preprocess the image
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_resize, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 1)

img_warped = image_processing.warp(img_gray, biggest_contour)
squares = image_processing.split_grid(img_warped)
predicted = image_processing.predict_digits(squares)
print(predicted)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. To predict the digits, I'm using a model I trained on data from the MNIST dataset and a dataset with various sudoku digits found here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kshitijdhama/printed-digits-dataset/code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't reproduce without sample images and all the resources needed to run your script.

Comment: @stateMachine Okay, how is best to do that - share the link to source code on github? Thanks